# TextView is null after onCreateView : nullpointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview, fragment

I have tried a number of solutions submitted to stack overflow, but none have helped me so far. The problem occurs when a button listener is triggered in another fragment which calls the parent activity. The parent activity calls this fragments `updateValue()` method (see below). In `onCreateView()` from my Fragment, I have the following code:

**Result.class extends Fragment**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.result, container, false);         
    resultTV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.resultTV);
    resultTV.setText(resultTV.getText().toString() + "test!");
    return view;
}
```

This works perfectly.. However, when I call a method in the fragment from the parent activity the textview reference is null (null pointer exception). The exception occurs where `resultTV.setText()` is called.

```
public void updateValue(View v) {
    String text = ((Button)v).getText().toString();

    if(text.toLowerCase() == "c") resultTV.setText(DEFAULT_RESULT_TEXT);
    else resultTV.setText(resultTV.getText().toString() + text);
}
```

**The Exception**

```
10-09 16:32:59.091: E/AndroidRuntime(2324): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 16:32:59.091: E/AndroidRuntime(2324): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 16:32:59.091: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at com.test.Result.updateValue(Result.java:53)
10-09 16:32:59.091: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at com.test.Main.onBasicButtonClicked(Main.java:65)
10-09 16:32:59.091: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at com.test.Basic$7.onClick(Basic.java:120)
10-09 16:32:59.091: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
10-09 16:32:59.091: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
10-09 16:32:59.091: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-09 16:32:59.091: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-09 16:32:59.091: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-09 16:32:59.091: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-09 16:32:59.091: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 16:32:59.091: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-09 16:32:59.091: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-09 16:32:59.091: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-09 16:32:59.091: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Edit:**

Main has a few fragment: `basic` and `scientific` fragments are simply buttons. The `matrix` fragment is not yet used, so we can ignore that one. `result` fragment is where the `TextView` in question is found.

**Main.class (Main activity class)**

```
public class Main extends Activity implements 
OnBasicButtonClickedListener, 
OnScientificButtonClickedListener, 
OnMatrixButtonClickedListener {

private FragmentManager     fm = getFragmentManager();
private FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
private Basic               basic = new Basic();
private Scientific          scientific = new Scientific();
private Result              result = new Result();
private MatrixFragment      matrixFrag = new MatrixFragment();
private static final String LOG = "Main.class";

/* this list view will hold all submitted formulas */
private ListView formulaLV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if(findViewById(R.id.result) == null)
        ft.add(R.id.result, result);

    if(findViewById(R.id.basic) == null)
        ft.add(R.id.basic, basic);

    if(findViewById(R.id.scientific) == null)
        ft.add(R.id.scientific, scientific);

    if(findViewById(R.id.matrix) == null)
        ft.add(R.id.matrix, matrixFrag);
    ft.commit();        
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return false;
}

/*
 *  This method acts as a listener for fragment to fragment communication 
 *  from Basic fragment.
 */
public void onBasicButtonClicked(View v) {
    Log.i(LOG, ((Button)v).getText() + " button pressed!");
    result.updateValue(v);
}

/*
 *  This method acts as a listener for fragment to fragment communication 
 *  from Scientific fragment.
 */
public void onScientificButtonClicked(View v) {
    Log.i(LOG, ((Button)v).getText() + " button pressed!");
    result.updateValue(v);
}

@Override
public void matrixButtonClicked(View view) {
    // matrix button clicked 

}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that `onCreateView()` had called before you call `updateValue()`?

Comment: Why are you passing a View from your Activity to your Fragment?  You should never have to do this.

Comment: `resultTV` looks to be a variable from Activity class while you have another class variable in Fragment. But those 2 are different, no wonder you're getting this exception.

Comment: @gunar no, he calls this method from parent Activity. So result is declaring and using only in fragment, as I understand..

Comment: @TaserPain: where is `public void updateValue(View v)`? Is it in fragment, or is it in Activity? My guess it's Activity

Comment: @lub0v - i logged both methods and they do submit in the correct sequence. updateValue() is called from the main activity when a button in another fragment is clicked (using a listener).

Comment: @SBerg413 - I do it so I can get the value of the button, I could also send the text of the button, but for the time being it shouldn't matter. It should be noted that this application is an advanced calculator, so there are many buttons.

Comment: @gunar - resultTV is a textview object in the result fragment and updateValue() is in the fragment.

Comment: @TaserPain that happens in all cases or only when you click button before you show this fragment?

Comment: @lub0v - the fragment is attached when the main activity starts. I can only click a button when all fragments are attached.

Comment: @TaserPain oh, please, put code from Activity..

Comment: @lub0v - see my edit for the activity class.

Comment: @TaserPain When result fragment displays? If it is not displays before you click the button, then your exception is obviously

Comment: @lub0v - the result fragment is visible when the button fragments are visible. [here is a screenshot](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=1e2f09a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The null pointer is probably because `resultTV` isn't showing to `updateValue()` method. How are you declaring `resultTV` in the fragment class? You might want to try declaring it as static if you're going to instantiate multiple instances of the class and you want it to stay the same over time

You also might want to try

```
TextView resultTV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.resultTV);
```

in the `updateValue` method

Comment: Declaring `resultTV` as `static` would mean that any additional fragments created would update the reference to _their_ `resultTV` - so FragmentA would be updating FragmentB's text view in the `updateValue` method. Oh dear.

Comment: they are in the same class, so they should definitely have access to each other. There is only a single instance.

Comment: Making `resultTV` static solved the problem.
`private static TextView resultTV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.resultTV);`